# UITableView re-order control - hide white line?

Tags: uitableview

[image: UITableView Re-order Control]

Is is possible to get rid of this white line that shows up when my UITableView is in editing mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the solution:

Remove it be iterating through subviews in visible cells:

```
-(void)editTableView {
    [self setEditing:YES animated: YES];
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        for (UIView *control in cell.subviews) {
            if (control.frame.size.width == 1.0f) {
                control.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove it for any cells being displayed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.editing) {
        for (UIView *control in cell.subviews) {
            if (control.frame.size.width == 1.0f) {
                control.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            }
        }
    }
}
```